# Unable to pan a canvas - Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have seen lot of posts which demonstrate how to move objects in a Canvas but what I need is, a way to move either
1. the entire canvas along with its every child
or
2. move every object manually (which is certainly not advisable)

I have put my Canvas in a ScrollViewer. 
My actual issue is : I m trying to zoom the canvas using ScaleTransform but after zooming, i also need to move the scroll viewer to a point such  that the clicked point is at the center after zooming.

I tried Canvas.SetLeft() and Canvas.SetTop() but bad luck..

Any idea?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with the ScrollViewer to make it scroll its content to a particular offset by using `ScrollToVerticalOffset` and `ScrollToHorizontalOffset`.

You'll need to calculate the correct offset by taking into account the size of the "viewport" i.e. the area that you can see of the content, and the zoom level.

- http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/center-zoom-wpf-problem-159135.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for what you are doing:

http://autoscroller.codeplex.com/